# Change current destination label in navigation

Tags: android, navigation

I want change current destination label. But not change label before navigate to another fragments and back.

```
findNavController().currentDestination?.label="${it.size} Musics"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the navigation graph xml file. This is an example :

```
<fragment
    android:label="{size}"
    <argument
        android:name="size"
        app:argType="integer" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: how can i pass data to nav graph?

Comment: so you pass it when you use the findNavController().navigate() method and using actions in the nav_graph xml file.  Read up the documentation here : https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data